# How do I debug an Access violation in the field?

Tags: delphi

An application in the field is getting this message intermittently:

[image]

I am not able to reproduce this on my machine.  I have also traced what I believe is the relevant code and can't find any access to uninitialized objects.

I've never had to deal with this kind of problem.

I did a build with madExcept and unfortunately the program does not crash once it is bundled.

Any opinions on madExcept vs EurekaLog for finding this kind of thing? I've never used FastMM. Would it be useful in his situation? (Delphi 2010) Any suggested flags to set in FastMM?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: @user205376: The module name would not provide you with any information that would help answer this question. And, I'm not interested in advertising the name of the program that has this problem.  I don't know if it was you who down-voted this question, but it would be helpful if whoever did so indicated why. If it's for my omission of the module name, a down-vote seems a bit heavy-handed to me...

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason for a downvote.  He's perfectly justified in hiding the filename, it's not going to do us any good.  I voted it back to zero.

Comment: +1 to teach the person who downvoted a lesson :-> (and to give Robert some mental support: I know how extremely frustrating hunting down those errors can be). @Robert: can you explain in more detail what kind of application this is? DB? Communication? DLL libraries? Any info might give us a clue to help you further.

Comment: +1 also, this is a good question.

Comment: A lesson? I'm still convinced what hiding something have negative impact on the chances to receive good consulting. Requests for more details/info/clues proves.

Comment: Yeah, besides some module names seem to be more ominous then others, when I get an AV, crash or BSOD the module name is most probably some 'Project1.exe'.

Comment: @FreeConsulting you don't provided your name, location, age, website, or any other thing that can identify you. Your argument is not valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note the very low address you are attempting to read.  This sort of error almost certainly means you attempted to dereference a nil pointer even if you can't find one.

Given your description of the behavior I would suspect you've got a memory stomp going on--something is blasting a zero on top of the pointer to an object.  When you change things you move things around and the stomp moves to someplace harmless.

Turn on both range checking and overflow checking.

Note the offending object must be at least 3C0 bytes in size--this should help narrow it down, most objects will be smaller than this.

What I have done in the past with such errors that only show in the field is put logging checkpoints in--a bunch of lines that display something in an out of the way place--a simple sequence of numbers is fine.  Find out what number is showing when it crashes and you know which of you checkpoints was the last to execute.  If that doesn't narrow it down enough you can repeat the process now that you've narrowed it down.

Answer (score 5):

With a full map file you can identify the exact point in the code where this occurs. I hope you have a full map file for this image!  Subtract $00401000 from the address at which the exception is raised ($007ADE8B in your case) and that corresponds to the values in the map file.

Having done that you know which object is nil and from there it is usually not too hard to work out what is going on.

One of the most common ways for this to occur is when a constructor raises an exception. When this occurs the destructor runs. If you access, in a destructor, a field that has not been initialised, and do anything other than call Free on it, then you will get an exception like this.

Comment: Does this ever work? It seems to me like all AVs pop up in RTL or other standard functions. Unless one also has access to a stack trace, knowing the line of code where the error occurred is very unlikely to help.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund Good point. It can work and if you've nothing else to go on then this is the first thing to try.

Comment: Calling `Free` on a null reference is always safe. That's *why* the `InitInstance` method sets everything to all-bits-zero prior to calling the constructor proper. It's always safe to just call `Free` on everything in the destructor even if the constructor terminated abnormally.

Comment: Yes @Rob, calling Free is fine, it's calling anything else that isn't fine. Perhaps I need to re-word my answer.

Comment: No, I just need to re-read your answer — I apparently missed where you said "anything other than."

Comment: @David, thanks for the suggestion, which I'll try. What's the significance of the magic number $00401000. Shouldn't I be able to use the IDE's "Go to address" with the address reported in the error message?

Comment: @robert addresses in the map file are relative to that magic number.

Comment: You can find the specific magic number at the top of the file. Eg:  Start Length Name Class
 0001:00401000 0018F669CH _TEXT                  CODE

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a memory overwrite where changing memory layout (your machine vs field machine or adding madExcept) makes the overwrite change something harmless.

FastMM is great at of making this kind of problems happen more consistently (and finding their source). Download the full version of FastMM, add it as the first unit of your project, and turn on FullDebugMode on its settings.

It might cause the problem to be reproduceable in your machine right away. If not, don't forget to deploy FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll with your application for testing. Keep madExcept on and let it embed the .map file for call stacks.